# Highschool Math Competition questions - Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is was part of the first round of the hms (Hellenic Mathematical Society) for the 12th grade. The questions are now online so I feel safe posting this. This problem seemed a bit too easy to me so I'm wondering if I missed something with my solution.

**Problem 1** 
$f:\mathbb{N}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with  $f(D_f)\subseteq \mathbb{N}^* \hspace{0.5em}  $ and satisfies for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$:
\begin{align*}
f(6n+7)&=6f(n)+7 \tag{1}\\
\text{and }f(7n-1)&=7f(n)-1\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Find $f(2029).$

**My solution** 
$ (1),(2) (n=8) \Rightarrow f(55)=6f(8)+7$ (3) and $f(55)=7f(8)-1 \Leftrightarrow 6f(8)+7=7f(8)-1 \Leftrightarrow f(8)=8\qquad  (4)$

$6n+7=2029 \Leftrightarrow n=337 $

$(1) (n=337) \Rightarrow f(2029)=6f(337)+7\qquad (5)$

$6n+7=337 \Leftrightarrow n=55$

$(1)(n=55) \Rightarrow f(337)=6f(55)+7 \Leftrightarrow f(337)=6(6f(8)+7)+7 \Rightarrow f(337)=337$ (from (4))

$(5) \Rightarrow f(2029)=6*337+7=2029$

I know there should be easier ways to solve this (like proving $f(n)=n$ first) but this is still correct right?

There was another problem that I in the end didn't manage to solve though.

**Problem 2**

$Let \hspace{0.5em} a,b \in [0,+\infty]:\hspace{0.5em} a+b=2.$ Find the minimum and maximum value of $A=8(a^3 +b^3)-3(a^4+b^4)
$

I tried turning this into a multivariable function $f(a,b)\hspace{0.3em}$and finding the min and max using partial derivatives and wasted all my time with that. And even now, I can't reach a conclusion.

Comment: My apologies, I  don't know how I messed up the functions this badly(dyslexia). Everything is correct now.

Comment: $A$ is really a function of only one variable, e.g. when you put $b=2-a$.

Comment: Agreed, it was a dumb way of going about it and I didn't really realize it until it was too late